# What is the ...(ellipsis) operator in c?

Tags: c

I happened to stumble upon the following piece of c code involving a `...` operator.

```
struct sam {
        int b;
        int a;
};

struct sam arr[10] = {
        [0 ... 9] = {.a = 1}
};
```

It does the work of initializing the `a` attribute of each struct in the array to `1`. What is this operator doing? This is all very new to me, are there any other places where this operator is used?

Comment: TLDR: This isn't any standard C but a GNU extension. Beware of portability issues if you go this way.

Comment: The ellipsis token is also used in function prototypes for variadic functions, for example `int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);` (but in that context it's not an operator).